# Why do shared items not show up in Graph API notification requests

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-fql

I am currently implementing an android application that checks a user's notifications periodically using the Graph API using the following query: /me?fields=notifications

I've noticed that whenever someone shares an item on the user's wall there is no notification returned from my request. So far I've seen this happen with sharing pictures and sharing video. I've tried using FQL and the Graph Explorer and neither one returns the notification, however on the user's facebook page it shows up.

I do have the manage_notifications permission and can see notifications of wall posts, invites to events, likes or comments on photos the user posted.

It appears that this is the same problem as: [Missing items in Notifications response](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/9325576/735125) but that's over a year old without an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to use the "include_read=true" extension? Maybe the notification is already read and isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Facebook updated the graph api, this is now working with no changes needed on my end.